# Add quotation mark programatically to EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I created an `EditText` where users can type a sentence in it. I would like to automatically add quotation marks to it at the start and end of the sentence.

For example, If a user type: `Believe you can and you're halfway there.`, I would like it to show in the EditText as:

[image]

If there is an option to add an image of a quotation mark and to make sure that it moves with the length of the string it could also do the job.

I tried something like this but my app crashes:

```
et_Quote.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        et_Quote.setText( "\" " + s.toString() + "\" ");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onTextChanged` you are calling `setText`, which calls `onTextChanged` inside which you are calling `setText` and so on... locked in loop, UI thread hangs

Consider adding some flag preventing multiple `onTextChanged` calls in a row

```
et_Quote.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    private boolean hold = false;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(hold) return;
        hold = true;
        et_Quote.setText( "\" " + s.toString() + "\"");
        hold = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Note that with every character entered into `et_Quote` you are adding `"` at the beginning and end of `String`, so there will be multiple `"` characters, two per every character entered. add some code for checking if first/last character is already a `"`, if yes then don't add it obviously

```
boolean isFirst = s.length() != 0 && s.charAt(0) == '"';
boolean isLast = s.length() != 0 && s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '"';
String toSet = (isFirst ? "" : "\" ") + s.toString().trim() + (isLast ? "" : "\"");
```

`trim()` method removes unnecessary whitespaces at the beginning and end of `String` (you can't call it on `CharSequence`, thus `toString()` used in there

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using hard text you can try this out.**

```
 android:text='"Hello"'
```

**If not then try this out.**

```
  InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        char[] chars = {'\'','"'};
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (new String(chars).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(index))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: not a hard text mate, a text from an edittext